# iMac 17" 2nd monitor question

Tags: imac, display, hardware-recommendation

I have a 17" iMac that I want to hook-up a 2nd monitor to. I bought an adaptor on eBay, but the plug does not match the back of my computer. It's not a Thunderbolt or FireWire. Not sure what kind of adaptor I need or what it is called. I have a photo, but not sure how to post it here.

Comment: Just post the photo anywhere online and copy/paste the link to it in your question

Comment: Check the specification! It's on Apple's website somewhere!

Comment: 17" iMac could be anything from 2002 to late 2006. As Dan J stated, it could be a mini-DVI or mini-VGA adapter that you need. Supplying the Model Identifier from System Info would be MOST helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you bought a *very* old iMac, its external display port is most likely [mini-DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DVI). If you have something as old as a G4 (the "desk lamp"-looking iMacs), it may be a [mini-VGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-VGA) port. A helpful resource for identifying your model and seeing details of its capabilities is [everymac.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/index-imac.html) - those are the only options I see for any of the 17-inch iMac models.